# How to link cuda library to cpp project/files with Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, nvidia, clion

I am trying to write a gui program using the gtk libraries and do some matrix operations with the cuda libraries, however I get an error when trying to link the cuda libraries in my project. My Cmake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)


find_package(CUDAToolkit)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${CUDA_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp bob.h bob.cu)
target_link_libraries(untitled1 ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY})
```

But I get the following error

```
-- Unable to find cuda_runtime.h in "/usr/lib/cuda/include" for CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR.
-- Unable to find cudart library.
-- Could NOT find CUDAToolkit (missing: CUDAToolkit_INCLUDE_DIR CUDA_CUDART) (found version "11.2.67")
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
```

I am on Pop OS 21.10 (Ubuntu), I can use the Cuda libraries and nvcc outside of this project, so I know it is installed and working properly. I just don't know how to link the cuda libraries to a non cuda project.

#### Edit: Working CMakeLists.txt down below thx to dhyun

```
# Set the minimum version of cmake required to build this project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

# Set the name and the supported language of the project
project(final CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

# Use the package PkgConfig to detect GTK+ headers/library files
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

# Setup CMake to use GTK+, tell the compiler where to look for headers
# and to the linker where to look for libraries
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Add other flags to the compiler
add_definitions(${GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER})

# Add an executable compiled from files:
add_executable(final main.cu showtext.h)

target_link_libraries(final ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})

# Idk what this does or if it's necessary, but it works with it and was there on creation
# So I'm keeping it :)
set_target_properties(final PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for your exact setup, but I've had success with CMake and CUDA on Ubuntu by directly enabling CUDA as a language in the project declaration rather than using `find_package(CUDAToolkit)`.

Something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(untitled1 LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp bob.h bob.cu)
target_link_libraries(untitled1 ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

I believe `cudart` is linked automatically, but you will need to specify any other libraries you use (`cufft`, `cublas`, `cudnn`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I was looking for. My original CMakeLists.txt had some wrong lines, so I'm going to post the correct one down below in case anyone needs to link the GTK Libraries to the CUDA compiler.